# How to aggregate results on a single row changing with "case when"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following issue:

```
Select owner name,  animal,
From DB


John   cat     
John   dog     
John   Lion
John   Tiger
```

I would like to filter by domestic animal and wild ones so:

```
Select name, 
       (case when animal like ('cat','dog') then 'domestic' else 'wild' end) as type
from DB   



John Domestic
John Domestic  
John Wild
John Wild
```

I would like something like:

```
John   2 Domestic
John   2 Wild
```

How to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just another three options

```
Select [Owner Name]
      ,[Type]       = case when animal in ('cat','dog') then 'Domestic' else 'Wild' end
      ,Cnt          = Count(*)
 From  DB
 Group By [Owner Name]
         ,case when animal in ('cat','dog') then 'Domestic' else 'Wild' end
```

**Or if you rather `NOT` replicate the CASE**

```
Select *
      ,Cnt = count(*)
 From  (
        Select [Owner Name]
              ,[Type]       = case when animal in ('cat','dog') then 'Domestic' else 'Wild' end
         From  DB
       ) src
 Group By [Owner Name]
         ,[Type]
```

As **CharlieFace** pointed out, `CROSS APPLY` !!

```
Select A.[Owner Name]
      ,B.[Type]
      ,Cnt = count(*)
From  DB A
Cross Apply ( values ( case when animal in ('cat','dog') then 'Domestic' else 'Wild' end)  ) B([Type])
Group By A.[Owner Name]
        ,B.[Type]
```

**Results**

```
Owner Name  Type        Cnt
John        Domestic    2
John        Wild        2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use aggregation:

```
Select name, 
       (case when animal like ('cat','dog') then 'domestic' else 'wild' end) as type,
       count(*)
from DB  
group by name, (case when animal like ('cat','dog') then 'domestic' else 'wild' end);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
      name ,  
      IF(animal = 'dog' ||  animal = 'cat' , 'Domestic', 'Wild') as type , 
      count(*) 
FROM animals 
GROUP BY  name , type
```

Comment: Just curious ... what database were you targeting ?

Comment: Mysql Database i am referring here